# Is there a way to force apache to return 404 instead of 403?

Tags: security, apache, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403

Is there a way how I can configure the Apache web server to return a 404 (not found) error code instead of 403 (forbidden) for some specific directories which I want to disallow to be accessed?

I found some solutions suggesting the use of mod_rewrite, like e.g.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ /404 [L]
```

As the purpose of sending 404 instead of 403 is to obfuscate the directory structure, this solution is too revealing, because it redirects to some different location which makes it obvious that the directory originally accessed does in fact exist.

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548156/problem-redirecting-403-forbidden-to-404-not-found) solve your problem?

Comment: I didn't consider this question when I first saw it (too confusing), but after a second glance I found the line I've been looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) as in e.g.

```
RedirectMatch 404 /\.
```

does the trick, it prohibits access to all files or directories starting with a dot, giving a "404 Not Found" error.

From the Apache manual: "The Redirect[Match] directive maps an old URL into a new one by asking the client to refetch the resource at the new location." By default, [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) sends a 302 return code, but it can also return other status codes as shown above.

Comment: +1, but to match a single dot anywhere in the url path, do we really need the quotes and the dot-star? I.e., can't we just do `RedirectMatch 404 /\.` instead of `RedirectMatch 404 ".*\/\..*"` ?

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig it returns 403 for ".git/.htaccess"and ".git/.php" instead  of 404

Comment: @Awaaaaarghhh, that's likely because you have a `FilesMatch` directive in your apache configuration that takes precedence. A custom `ErrorDocument` for 403 as suggested in Tomer's answer would cover this case, too, but requires `php`.

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig `but requires php`, no, why php?! - you can use also static html documents like "my404error.html" for your custom ErrorDocument!  `that's likely because you have a FilesMatch dir`, no, i tested it without `RedirectMatch`. anyway thank you! :) I was able to fix everything, now all requests return 404 error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61199481/4224741 (I used `FilesMatch`). I tested a lot & read apache docs, but was not able to use `RedirectMatch` properly in that specific case.

Comment: Because with `html` you won't be able to change 403 to 404.

Answer (score 10):

You can make something like this:

**.htaccess**

> ErrorDocument 403 /error/404.php

**404.php**

```
<?php
$status = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS'] = 404;
header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' ' . $status);
?>

404 Error
```

Comment: *Why is this not upvoted enough?* I used this solution. It's very straightforward. However, since I have PHP >= 5.4.0, I simply used `<?php http_response_code(404); ?>` at the top of the `404.php` page. This way I can use `ErrorDocument *** any code *** /error/404.php` and they will all become `404` in the HTTP header.

Comment: What if I want to send all requests to a unique index.php front controller script and have it decide if 404.php should be executed?

Comment: @ADTC, it's not relevant to the question, which was how to ask Apache to do this, not PHP.

Comment: @ChrisCogdon How to ask Apache to do this > this is exactly what `.htaccess`, an Apache-readable file, does. So in the end, this answer is still asking Apache to do this. Apache executes the `404.php` file when there is a 403 error. PHP parses the file and sends the output _through Apache web server_ to the browser. Where's the irrelevancy in this?

Comment: @tonix you simply need to redirect all the error codes to `index.php` and write the PHP script in it to do the needful (check and decide if 404, then include 404.php otherwise include some other content).

Answer (score 6):

After having the same problem, I ended up with the following .htaccess file

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ - [R=404,NC]
```

The 1st and 3rd line ensure that you can't list the folder content, and if you do it you will receive a 404 error.
The [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html) directive ensures that this rewrite rule only applies to main domain. Since I have several subdomains, without the rewritecond, accessing www.mydomain.com/subdomain was also returning a 404, which was not what I intended.

Comment: This works well for me. Just one issue is the way `Options -Indexes` works: /img/ (which doesn't exist) correctly returned a 404, but /img/ (which does exist and I want access to, but not a directory listing for) returned a 403. So, what I did was remove `Options -Indexes` and just make sure the regexes (that specify allowed files) never match just a directory name.

Comment: *That is not a subdomain, but a sub-site..., could be bypassed by RewriteCond for directory check (... -d ...)...

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion making this task in `.htaccess` is quite ugly solution.

It is possible to make it in apache configuration. Take a look:

Add to your apache config:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /404
```

Then restart apache:

```
service apache2 restart
```

That is all.

Comment: That line alone oesn't work (no matter whether you put it in htaccess or apache config).