# Rewrite requests to directory with htaccess to 404 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to rewrite requests to directory `secret` (http://example.com/secret) with .htaccess file to show always `404 Not Found` error. I'm using Apache 2.4.

It should work for those cases:

- /secret/treasure.php (all files and directories in that folder)
- /secret
- /secret/
- /secret?42
- /secret/?23
- **/secret/.php** <kbd>→</kbd> should result in 404 Not Found
- **/secret/.htaccess** <kbd>→</kbd> should result in 404 Not Found

My .htaccess rules block everything except the last two cases (I'm getting 403 error, but it should be 404):

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^secret.*$ - [R=404,L]
```

I would like to rewrite requests `/secret/.php` and `/secret/.htaccess` to "404 Not Found error".

---

**UPDATE:** This is a bit hacky but seems to block everything

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^secret.*$ - [R=404,L]

RewriteRule ^404_error$ - [R=404,L]

<FilesMatch "^\.">
    order allow,deny

    # 403 error
    deny from all

    # Rewrite 403 error to 404 error
    # Must be an absolute path
    ErrorDocument 403 /404_error
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: detailed answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717130/htaccess-make-a-directory-invisible

Comment: If you do not want a directory to get published, then why do you puglish it in the first place? Keep it outside the http hosts ``DOCUMENT_ROOT`` folder...

Comment: @arkascha your argument is legid, but in some projects you just have to do it. Additionally moving documents out of public_html might it make at first glance "less vulnerable", but it is not true, because if you have LFI or any arbitrary file disclosure vulnerabilities they will not save you too. Additionally if you fail to configure your directory settings correctly, then everything might happen and even moving documents out of public_html will not protect you.