# .htaccess 404 error on real path

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want the following:

1. `www.bla-bla.com/` --> `www.bla-bla.com/php/index.php`
2. `www.bla-bla.com/php/index.php` --> `www.bla-bla.com/php/error.php`

I have tried the following but doesn't work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?$  /php/index.php [S=1]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/php/index\.php
RewriteRule (.*)? /php/error.php [R=404]
```

What can I do to deny access from real path?

---

```
URL=http://localhost
 (3) [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/ -> 
 (3) [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/] applying pattern '/php/index\.php' to uri ''
 (3) [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/ -> 
 (3) [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/] applying pattern '^(/?)$' to uri ''
 (2) [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/] rewrite '' -> '/php/index.php'
 (1) [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/] internal redirect with /php/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
 (3) [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/php/index.php -> php/index.php
 (3) [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/] applying pattern '/php/index\.php' to uri 'php/index.php'
 (3) [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/php/index.php -> php/index.php
 (3) [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/] applying pattern '^(/?)$' to uri 'php/index.php'
 (1) [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/] pass through C:/xampp/htdocs/php/index.php
URL=http://localhost/php/index.php
 (3) [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/php/index.php -> php/index.php
 (3) [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/] applying pattern '/php/index\.php' to uri 'php/index.php'
 (3) [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/php/index.php -> php/index.php
 (3) [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/] applying pattern '^(/?)$' to uri 'php/index.php'
 (1) [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/] pass through C:/xampp/htdocs/php/index.php
```

Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteRule /php/index\.php /php/error.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(/?)$ /php/index.php [QSA,L]
```

Wtf is going on here?

Comment: Do you mean to say that everything in `bla-bla.com/` should rewrite to the same thing in `bla-bla.com/php/` , but you don't want users to be able to access anything by directly going to `bla-bla.com/php/`?

Comment: this is allmost, my main goal
But especially i want that i asked
Thx for reply

Comment: When visitors wants to browse bla-bla.com/ apache executes and send php/index.php file, but when a visitor want to browse bla-bla.com/php/index.php apache executes and seand bla-bla.com/php/error.php file..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to force apache to return 404 instead of 403?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486304/is-there-a-way-to-force-apache-to-return-404-instead-of-403) - and you might be looking for the `L` flag.

Comment: RewriteRule ^/?$  /php/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?php/index\.php$ /php/error.php

Even this lines solvee the problem..I have a xampp installation right now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
# If the actual request is for /php/index.php, rewrite to error.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /php/index.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^php/index\.php /php/error.php  [L]

# Otherwise check if root request and rewrite to /php/index.php
RewriteRule ^$ /php/index.php  [L]
```

---

EDIT: responding to comments:

Without the[L] flag, it will try to apply the next rule. mod_rewrite will *always* send it back through the rewrite engine after a URI has been rewritten. It will continue to do so until the URI went through the engine unchanged. The first condition checks that the *actual request* is for `/php/index.php`, so that the rewritten URI won't match. Example:

1. Someone requests http://bla-bla.com/
2. first rule doesn't match because the HTTP Request is `GET / HTTP/1.1`
3. second rule rewrites to /php/index.php
4. mod_rewrite sends the rewritten URI back through the rewrite engine
5. first rule doesn't match because eventhough the URI is now "/php/index.php", **the original HTTP Request is still the same**: `GET / HTTP/1.1`
6. second rule doesn't match because the URI is now "/php/index.php" and not "/".
7. rewrite engine stops because base URI is unchanged.

Example 2:

1. Someone requests http://bla-bla.com/php/index.php
2. first rule matches because the HTTP Request is `GET /php/index.php HTTP/1.1`
3. URI is rewritten to `/php/error.php`
4. second rule doesn't match
5. URI is sent back through the rewrite engine
6. first rule's *condition* matches because the HTTP Request is still the same
7. however, the URI isn't '/php/index.php' now so the actual rule doesn't match
8. second rule still doesn't match
9. reiwrte engine stops because base URI is unchanged.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l says: 
It is possible that as the rewritten request is handled, the .htaccess file or <Directory> section may be encountered again, and thus the ruleset may be run again from the start.

Comment: So, [L] flag means: GO to end, then start again with the new URL
If any of rules doesn't match stop proccessing..angryyyyy

Comment: See my edit to explain what's going on. Also note that the first rule needed to be tweaked. Try it again and see if you still get errors.

Comment: very good expplanation, what's going wrong..
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+ /php/index.php  [NC]
must be RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+/php/index.php  [NC] ?
The above code doesn't do my job..
Thx for reply..

Comment: Sorry, forgot a backslash on that line

Comment: I want to make 1 more things. 1)404 Redirect for all .php files
(the request wouldn't be a subrequest)
I try this: RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ (.+)\.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /php/error.php?url=$1  [L,NS]
but i see a 500 internal server error

Comment: try adding a `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/php/error.php` before that rewrite rule, otherwise it will loop.

Comment: you are right
THis also works fine:
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ (.+)\.php  [NC]
RewriteRule [^/php/error\.php] /php/error.php  [L,NS]
THx

Answer (score 1):

use

```
ErrorDocument 404 /php/error.php
```

in .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Jon: I don't understand your solution.

Here's mine: first check if there's a try to access what you don't want (i.e. `/php/index.php`) and if so, redirect to error and stop everything. Then after (only *after*), you're sure it's not `/php/index.php` so apply your redirection:

```
RewriteRule /php/index\.php /php/error.php [L]
RewriteRule / /php/index.php [QSA,L]
```

Keep in mind that the **`[L]`** directive will stop immediately RewriteRules, so remove le last one if you want to add other RewriteRules.

Of course, if you want to redirect **ALL** the incoming requests to `php/index.php` and pass the URL as an argument here is the solution that *should* work (I say "should" because I haven't tested):

```
RewriteRule /php/index\.php /php/error.php [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /php/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Olivier