# Redirect banned IPs to 404 rather than 403

Tags: apache, redirect, http-status-code-403

I have a certain directory I only want accessible from within my office.  I have this working, and blocked just fine.  Here is what I have in my apache conf:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/live/protected>
  Order deny,allow
  allow from 1.1.1.1.1.1 # My office ip
  deny from all
</Directory>
```

Rather than create a custom 403 page, I would rather just send these people to 404 pages.  Is there a way in Apache I can have a conditional that if they are not coming from my office IP, I can just send them to the 404 page I have?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Denying via 404 instead of 403](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479198/denying-via-404-instead-of-403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

```
RedirectMatch 404 ".*\/\..*"
```

-> [Is there a way to force apache to return 404 instead of 403?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486304/is-there-a-way-to-force-apache-to-return-404-instead-of-403)
-> [Problem redirecting 403 Forbidden to 404 Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548156/problem-redirecting-403-forbidden-to-404-not-found)

Comment: Thanks, but I have seen both of those.  I am looking to only do this conditionally, based on IP.  Take a look at my sample config. I don't want to based this on just directory, rather also based on the IP.  Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

To change all 403,400 errors into 404 errors, put this at the end of **/etc/apache2/conf.d/localized-error-pages** OR into a **.htaccess** OR into your `<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>`

```
# Will raise a 404 error, because the file <fake_file_for_apache_404.php> doesn't exist.
# We change 403 or 400 to 404 !
ErrorDocument 400 /fake_file_for_apache_404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /fake_file_for_apache_404.php
# We need to rewrite 404 error, else we will have "fake_file_for_apache_404.php not found"
ErrorDocument 404 "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\"><html><head><title>404 Not Found</title></head><body><h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested URL <script type=\"text/javascript\">document.write(document.location.pathname);</script> was not found on this server.</p></body></html>"
ErrorDocument 500 "Server in update. Please comme back later."
```