# How to hide wp-admin from other users other than administrator and they get should get a HTTP 404 error on wordpress?

Tags: php, web, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I am designing my website on wprdpress. So to make it more secure I want this. if any user other than the administrator types on browser wp-admin after my domain name e.g "www.mydomain/wp-admin" should get a HTTP 404 error. How to get this please help.

Comment: how you will identify that it is not admin? you can put HTTP authentication on URL.

Comment: Then what about wp_login.php

Comment: After login it can be identified. And about wp-login.php i renamed it. So if someone types wp-login.php gets a HTTP 404 error. So it can done  by renaming wp-admin also but I don't know how to rename wp-admin and also its not healthy so is there any other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 add_action('admin_init', 'no_mo_dashboard');
function no_mo_dashboard() {
  global $wp_query;
  if (!current_user_can('manage_options') && $_SERVER['DOING_AJAX'] != '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php') {
  $wp_query->set_404();
  status_header( 404 );
  get_template_part( 404 ); exit();
  }
}
```

Paste the above code in functions.php. This restricts normal user access to dashboard and redirects to 404 page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for you reply it really worked but only one problem. it only works only when user is logged in and for non logged in users it gives wordpress error "you must log in to acces your admin area" but I want users who are not logged in also should get HTTP 404 error while trying to access wp-admin. I know by little modification it can be done please help.

Comment: But before login, you'll not be knowing who is admin or who is user. I think you can restrict url. But as far as i know, you can restrict dashboard only after user/admin is logged in.

Comment: before login it not possible for any user even administrator to access wp admin so I want to all users even administrator while accessing wp-admin before login should get HTTP 404 error instead of wordpress error.

Comment: but after login except administrator every user should get HTTP 404 error to access wp admin.

Comment: It means you have different login page other than wp-admin or wp-login. Is it?

Comment: In that case, just remove the if condition in the above posted answer and check if it works as you expect.

Comment: Yes i have different login page.Yes I removed the If condition and it is redirected to "http://mydomain.com/?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2mydomain.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1" and in the page it gives "Please login to continue".

Comment: Not getting what i expected.

Comment: Can we use !is_user_logged_in() there?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using ip addresses if you have them for the specific user's accounts.  You can restrict address using the .htaccess file see this [redirect to 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711871/redirect-banned-ips-to-404-rather-than-403) but you would have to know users ip address.  You wouldn't be able to access it from outside your regular space either, like starbucks.