# .htaccess 403 redirect to 404 Issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My directory structure is like this.

```
--index.html
--img
   --.htaccess
   --image.png
```

`index.html` simply loads `image.png`. When someone types `mysite.com/img`, I want to 1) prevent people from listing img directory and 2) Return `404` error instead of `403` when try to access the img folder.

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/548210/723962) SO answer, I've created an `.htaccess` file in the img folder with this content.

```
Options -Indexes
<FilesMatch /img(/?|/.*)>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

RedirectMatch 404 ^/img(/?|/.*)$
```

However, when I do this `index.html` itself can't find image.png anymore and it also gets a 404 error. If I remove the `RedirectMatch` line from `.htaccess` then it works but now mysite.com/img returns 403 error.

Is it possible for index.html to load the image and `mysite.com/img` returns a 404 response via .htaccess file? I'm very new to Apache, so not sure if these sounds naive or the requirements are kind of mutually exclusive/

Comment: Read about preventing hotlinks.

Comment: @hjpotter92, thanks. Will read about it.